# Random Pick from Array without duplicate

Tags: jquery

I need to pick an element from an array 10 different times without picking any duplicates in this process:

```
function raffle(){
   question_pool = Array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m);
   question = question_pool[Math.floor(Math.random()*question_pool.length)];
}
```

This is my function raflle(), when I execute it, I may get a result twice.

Here is the approach:

```
question_pool = Array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m);
maximum = 10;
minimum = 0;
question_stack = Math.floor(Math.random() * question_pool.length - minimum);
minimum = Math.min(minimum + 1, maximum);
question = question_pool.splice(question_stack,1);
question_pool.push(question);
```

Comment: don't push it back into the array. Once you remove it you can't pick it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use splice to remove selected questions from the question pool. Once all questions have been drawn then continue.

```
var question_pool = Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m");
do{
  var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * question_pool.length);;
  var question = question_pool[id];
  question_pool.splice(id, 1);
  console.log(question);
}while(question_pool.length > 0);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nc67chwn/

Subsequently, you could create a deep clone of the question_pool array and splice elements from that if you wanted to preserve your original question group.

Comment: Thanks! Perfekt. Seems legit!